# Trigger condition when DateTime field is null

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, conditional

I have a flow that triggers on `When an item or a file is modified` in a document library.

To stop it re-triggering when the item is updated, I'm checking that a DateTime field called `FlowModified` isn't within 2 minutes of the `Modified` time using this trigger condition:

```
@not(lessOrEquals(ticks(triggerBody()?['Modified']),ticks(addMinutes(triggerBody()?['FlowModified'],2))))
```

`FlowModified` has a default value, so for newly added files (though not for folders…), this is working fine.

The problem is that existing files in the library have nothing in `FlowModified`. And in this case it seems like `FlowModified` isn't returned at all in `triggerBody()` and I can't test its value.

Is there a way I can trigger my flow when `FlowModified` is empty as well as applying the condition above when `FlowModified` does contain a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR in the trigger condition to connect such pieces:

```
@or(condition1, condition2, condition3,...)
```

Try as following to add another condition: `equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/FlowModified'], null)`

```
@or(not(lessOrEquals(ticks(triggerBody()?['Modified']),ticks(addMinutes(triggerBody()?['FlowModified'],2)))),equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/FlowModified'], null))
```

More information for your reference:

https://tomriha.com/a-simple-way-to-create-a-trigger-condition-in-power-automate/

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. When I modify a file with nothing in the `FlowModified` field, the flow generates an error at the trigger (first) step: **One or more fields provided is of type 'Null', a different type is expected.**

Comment: (The question isn't about the **or** condition. I'm having trouble testing for the null/empty value in `FlowModified`.)

Comment: Oooo! I need to put the null test first in the or expression. Then once that is true, it doesn't go on to evaluate further things. I settled on `@or(empty(triggerBody()?['FlowModified']),not(lessOrEquals(ticks(triggerBody()?['Modified']),ticks(addMinutes(triggerBody()?['FlowModified'],2)))))`

Comment: The reason your one was failing is that `addMinutes` didn't like the null value. I don't really understand why this wasn't a problem in my question code… Oh well. It's working now.